# Display element outside the frame

Tags: java, swing, layout, icons, jframe

I have to realize this design with Java Swing (see screen shot).

[image]

Is it possible?  How can an element appear off the frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Add a `JToolBar` (non-floatable) to `JFrame` or parent `JPanel` (in the `BorderLayout.NORTH` position).
- Put an `Icon` inside a `JButton` and add to tool bar.
- Set "MODE DIAL" (or whatever) as the tool tip for the button.
- Repeat for each icon/button required.
- Use a PLAF to tweak the look.

Comment: Add PLAf+java and throw that into a search engine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a JWindow to contain your component.